# Почему веб приложения не зависимы от ос

Tags: java

Заранее извиняюсь за вопрос. Скорее всего он глупы и некорректный. Только начал учиться на прогера. Java...  Вот понял пока, что java это язык с промежуточным кодом и чтобы его запустить на компе нужна jre. Но пишут что веб приложения кроссбраузерные и что их можно запустить на любой ос. Но как так? Ведь у пользователя может не быть установлено jre. Или в понятие веб приложение входит что-то другое, а не программа например на Java (например). Ещё раз, извините, вопрос оч глупый. Но перерыл весь нет. Не понимаю (

Comment: Код java будет исполнятся на сервере, т.е. пользователю не нужно будет устанавливать jre.

Comment: Веб приложения обычно состоят из html+css+js и будут передаваться и выполняться у клиента (браузер). А сервер (например на java) будет работать у вас

Comment: Не будет установлена jre, не будет работать java-программа. К кросс-платформенности  это отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

Веб приложение делится на две части:
1. Фронтенд
2. Бекенд

Когда вы обращаетесь по адресу, вы обращаетесь на бекенд, ваш запрос обрабатывается и вы получаете страничку(HTML + CSS + JS). Все браузеры умеют и понимают как отрисовать страничку.

Бекенд можно писать на java, php, .net и тп, но на сервере должна быть установлена среда для работы приложения.

Это если в двух словах, на пальцах :)

Comment: Спасибо огромное)